# Getting an odd space between input-group-addon span and form-control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to Bootstrap, and am having an issue when using input-group and input-group-addon. I have tried the best I can to find someone else having the same problem, to no avail.

The input-group looks great on md size screen, but refuses to line up with the form control on any other screen size.

md:

[image: md screen size]

lg:

[image: lg screen size]

xs & sm

[image: xs & sm screen size]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight, new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
    <div class="input-group col-md-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weight, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">lbs</span>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight)
    </div>
</div>
```

I attempted pulling the addon span using "col-lg-pull-2", this had no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using additional CSS that we're not seeing?

Comment: The only other CSS that you don't see is that it is inside of a horizontal form.

Comment: @Deryck I'm really confused by your comment. It seems you are simply attacking me here. This is an issue with the usage of Bootstrap classes. I have not edited the default Bootstrap 3 classes.

Comment: @Gaby's solution works. There is another way to avoid issues like that too. Check out [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/). Your code would be cleaner

Comment: @Dmitry I was actually in the process of converting everything to TwitterBootstrapMVC when I asked this question and was waiting to fix this issue before I converted it. Of course, I didn't realize it would have fixed my issue in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.EditorFor` does not have a version where it accept html attributes as parameter..

Use `Html.TextBoxFor` instead..

Comment: Thank you much this worked great! And what do you know, it wasn't "strictly a CSS issue" and was in fact a MVC Razer issue.